# Running a Bash while loop over all similar files

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to write a while loop in Bash that runs over all instances of files that are of the form of

```
{number}.tst
```

for example, `1.tst`, `2.tst`, ... `50.tst`.

I do **not** want it to run over the file `tst.tst`.

How would I go about writing this? I assume I will need a boolean phrase and `[0-9]*` somewhere in there, but I am not entirely sure on the syntax.

Comment: Are your numbers all positive integers? :)

Comment: Correct, all positive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only need to exclude alphabetic names like your example `tst.tst` you could use a simple shell glob

```
for f in [0-9]*.tst; do echo "$f"; done
```

With bash *extended globs* (which should be enabled by default in Ubuntu)

given

```
$ ls *.tst
1.tst  2.tst  3.tst  4.tst  50.tst  5.tst  bar.tst  foo.tst
```

then `+([0-9])` means one or more decimal digits:

```
for f in +([0-9]).tst; do echo "$f"; done
1.tst
2.tst
3.tst
4.tst
50.tst
5.tst
```

You can check whether extended globbing is enabled using `shopt extglob` and set it if necessary using `shopt -s extglob` (and unset using `set -u extglob`).

Comment: This works for an echo loop, but the variable itself becomes [0-9]*.tst. How could I make it so just the numerical value is there? Say I would like to use the number associated with the file name later on in the script with a different name. 

For example, if the file name is 9.tst, but later on in the loop, I would like to apply changes to a file named 9-tst.tst. The numerical value at the beginning is the same, but the file cannot be opened because the script reads as 9.tst-tst.tst when trying to open.

Comment: @J.Doe you can remove the extension using [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) e.g. if `f` contains `9-tst.tst` then `"${f%.tst}"` will remove the shortest trailing string matching `.tst` to leave just `9-tst`

Comment: Now I seem to be running into another problem where the variable reads quite literally as [0-9]*-tst.tst when written into my full script.

Comment: @J.Doe that will happen if there are no matching files in the directory, and you did not set  the `nullglob` option (`shopt -s nullglob`)

Comment: Oh duh, it was just a path issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6):

From this **Stack Overflow** answer: [List files that only have number in names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527166/list-files-that-only-have-number-in-names):

```bash
find . -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.tst'
```

**OR**

Using find also has advantages when you want to do something with the files, e.g. using the built-in `-exec`, `-print0` and pipe to `xargs -0` or even (using Bash):

```bash
while IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
  # ...
done < <(find . -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.tst' -print0)
```

---

Note the other answers here my include files that aren't numbers if the filename starts with a digit. The answer posted here does not though. For example:

```bash
$ ls *.tst
12tst.tst  1.tst  2.tst

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.tst'
./1.tst
./2.tst
```

**NOTE:** Use `-maxdepth 1` argument to only list numbered files in the current directory and not in sub-directories.

Comment: Especially with "-exec", or the "-print0 | xargs -0" options, using "find" is clearly superior to shell globbing for non-trivial tasks: it handles all of the issues around weird characters in file names and argument length limits with grace and aplomb.

Comment: @minnmass Soooo true! I had a nightmare a few months ago around weird filenames that caused all kinds of headaches. In this case of where only simple filenames are used it's not a problem but perhaps it's good to future proof the code.

Comment: ``find`` is recursive, the ``ls`` variants are not. You may want to add the ``depth`` parameter to the find command line.

Comment: @allo Good point. But it also may be a benefit to list numbered files in sub-directories too. I've added `-maxdepth` to the answer with a note.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, there are no filenames of the form {number}{non-number}.tst, so one possible solution is to include all the filenames that *start* with a number:

```
for filename in [0-9]*.tst; do
    echo "$filename"  # Example command
done
```

Comment: Oh... so you mean `123foo.tst` would be included?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, any filename that starts with a number and ends with `.tst` would be included, regardless of what's in the middle.

Comment: I assume it's the same with steeldriver's recent edits then. I've edited my answer to show files like `123foo.tst` would be excluded.

Comment: @Win Yes, it's the same glob as in steeldriver's edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the files in numerical order, there's the `seq` command (read `man seq`).

```
for i in $( seq 1 50 ) ; do
    echo "Process ${i}.txt"
done
```

Comment: I don't get it. File `1.txt`, `10.txt` and `20.txt` might exist but doesn't your script simply list all potential filenames from `1.txt` to `50.txt`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yup, that's exactly it. The `*` glob in shell expands to *existing* filenames. Here's it's not a requirement, and if *you know*, files are there, there's no need to check for their existence. This is perfectly acceptable, although not efficient when the number of files gets large. Shell loops,especially that employ `seq` aren't efficient.  Whole programs written in C are more efficient, like `find` .

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy OK, I'm not sure I totally understand but what if there is a file named `51.txt` wouldn't that be excluded?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, that would be excluded. And again, this way is useful when you know that there are exactly files `1.txt` to `50.txt`. If you have files 1 to 51, then you'd do `seq 1 51`.  In other words, here you have more of your own control, with something like `+([0-9]).txt` you want shell to figure it out for  you. Basically, depends on how much you want shell to handle :)